# Display image to blade using cpanel

Tags: php, html, laravel

i'm using **GODADDY** as my host, now i deploy my project everything works but except this image how do i display the image which is save into my sql database using image **intervention package in Laravel**, i have no problem in saving the image it works the only problem is how to display it in my View..my controller will save it under the path of **public/uploads**

**Details:**  **$leads**=*model,* **uploads***=folder,***image***=database column*

**Note:** i have tried this following html code but still not working
all my item in public is move already to public_html except the **uploads folder**

```
<img src="{{ asset($leads->image) }}" />--this is not working
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/' . leads->image) }}" />--this is not working
<img src="{{ asset('uploads')}}/{{ $leads->image) }}" />--this is not working
<img src="{{ URL::asset('storage/uploads'.$leads->image) }}">
<img src="/uploads/{{$leads->image}}" >--only works in my local computer
```

**File System**

```
<?php
```

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Filesystem Disk
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
| by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
| based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
|
*/

'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
| reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
| will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
|
*/

'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Filesystem Disks
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
| may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
| been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
|
| Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "s3", "rackspace"
|
*/

'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],

],
```

];

can anyone point me to the right direction/ or tutorials..

Comment: you could check the path displayed by those not working script and work your way from there. Do an inspect element on the broken images and see what they have as a path.

Comment: you can just point your virtual host to laravel `public` folder rather than default `public_html`

Comment: @rkj how do i point my public?

Comment: do you have access to your server's apache ?

Comment: @hungrykoala yes i do inspect element i always end up 404

Comment: I mean what does it say on the image src? does it say public/somewhere/this/that/image?

Comment: your problem is, your `uploads` folder is inside `public` folder which is not accessible publicly because your web server pointing to public_html. Better you share your server directory structure.

Comment: @hungrykoala  yow thanks inspect element answer my problem haha i missed some / along the code thanks man..

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have found the answer i missed out some parts.

**Final Code:**

```
{{ URL::asset('public/uploads/'.$leads->image)}}
```